# What is the meaning of division by 2^k is zero cost?

Tags: math

Floor `(ax+b)/2^k`, where `2^k` is zero cost division, what does it mean, could you please explain anyone.

Comment: it's not zero cost, but the cost is very low since it can be done by a simple shift

Comment: If `k` is chosen equal to the register size, you may do this even without a shift, just by dropping the register that holds the low word of the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's nice, could you please show a workout example if you don't mind? Floor[a/d]=Floor (ax+b)/2^k, how to shift or what happen if we choose equal size register? Please

Comment: This all happens inside the compiler, you don't get direct access to it from a high-level programming language. Knowing about using shift for divisions helps to write performant algorithms and programs.